# Data URI saved JPG images create black images on upload with php imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image, gd, data-uri

I am using following code to upload

```
//width,new_width,height,new_height are set
$tmp_filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height); //resample image          

if(($ext=='jpg') | ($ext=='jpeg')){
    //if image to be uploaded is jpg
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_filename); 
}
else{
    //if image to be uploaded is png
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_filename);
}

//to convert to jpg
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

$done=imagejpeg($image_p, $output_dirrectory."/".$image_name.".jpg",95); //95% quality
```

Now, the problem is, when I save a image from any other website which was generated using Data URI, it get saved on my local machine as JPG image. When I try to upload same image with following code, it created black image.

I could't figure out the problem. I hope solution lies in imagecreatefromstring, but I don't know how that will work out with following code? Please suggest any solution?

Comment: I think you'll need to post more code. How exactly is data being submitted for the case it does not work? If the image data is in a form post, then you may be right about imagecreatefromstring. But if you are uploading it as a file, you may be trying to upload a shortcut to an image which won't work.

Comment: You don't seem to be setting $width or $height. If they are zero it will just zoom nothing to a full blank square.

Comment: mentioned in top comments, they are set... this code works with other jpg and png files. Just not with some jpg files.

Comment: ok, but how can you set them before you even loaded the image? You don't know the width and height of the image being uploaded.

Comment: i like to use exif_imagetype to determine what type of image (this must be enabled in php.ini) Then you need to handle possible errors and  you'll get an idea where things are going wrong.

Comment: I have found the problem. The file saved on my computer is actually png but with extension .jpg. I check file type from a website and it returned PNG. Now when I check file extension in background using this code `$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); `, it return jpg.

Comment: then using exif_imagetype would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
$width = imageSX($image);
$height = imageSY($image);
```

before the call to imagecopyresampled